# When plotting dataframe - no data is actually plotted and the chart is blank

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Created new data frame called **lf** which is a result of adding and subtracting columns from other data frames.

```
lf = (wf['WALCL'] - (rf['RRPONTSYD'] + tf['WTREGEN']))
lf.dropna()
```

When I dropped the NA out of the table I got the following:

```
DATE   
2018-01-24    4441011.511  
2018-01-31    4418888.959  
2018-02-07    4420492.944  
2018-02-14    4434626.801  
2018-02-21    4411400.152  
                 ...     
2022-12-21    8561744.255  
2022-12-28    8548448.071  
2023-01-04    8504775.833  
2023-01-11    8506015.490  
2023-01-18    8486568.304
Length: 261, dtype: float64
```

The data frame is populated with a date column and a column full of data

I tried plotting this data frame as follows:

```
lf.plot(figsize = (15,3), legend = False, style='k', title = 'Liabilities');
```

but the plot was blank with no values:

[Blank Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0hSA.png)

Any ideas as how this can be corrected? Thanks!

Comment: Does it work better if you simplify the call to something like `lf.plot(color='blue')`?  Could you try out some variations to find out what works?  Do you have the latest matplotlib and pandas installed?

Comment: Nope, that did not work either. It's strange because I am able to plot data directly from other CSV files.  For this data set I manipulated the data and then when plotting its blank.